# How can I reference, not copy, data from another tab?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

We have a large script in a Google Sheet. The first tab is the *whole* script, some 1500 lines. Sometimes folks like to open a new tab called like "Scene 1" and copy all the Scene 1 lines into a new tab to edit it.

This then requires them at some point to copy "Scene 1" back into the "Script" tab. This is error prone and creates an issue where the dialog in one tab is diverging from another.

What I'd love to do is be able to set up tabs where the data in "Scene 1" , is a *reference* to the stuff in "Script" so that any changes in the "Scene 1" tab are reflected back in the "Script" tab. Is this doable? I haven't managed it yet.

Answer (score 1):

in your **Script** tab paste this in **A1** cell:

```
={'Scene 1'!A1:1000}
```